# Beautifulsoup scrape content of a cell beside another one

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape the content of a cell besides another cell of which I know the name e.g. "**Staatsform**", "**Amtssprache**", "**Postleitzahl**" etc. In the picture the needed content is always in the right cell.

[image]

The basic code is the following one, but I am stuck with it:

```
source_code = requests.get('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg')
plain_text = source_code.text                       
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")     
stastaform = soup.find(text="Staatsform:")...???
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the HTML fragment that describes both cells of interest.

Comment: Do you want just the text from the cells, or something more?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to exercise care in limiting the search to what is called the 'Infobox' in the English-language wikipedia. Therefore, I searched first for the heading 'Basisdaten', requiring that it be a `th` element. Not exactly definitive perhaps but more likely to be. Having found that I looked for `tr` elements under 'Basisdaten' until I found another `tr` including a (presumed different) heading. In this case, I search for 'Postleitzahlen:' but this approach makes it possible to find any/all of the items between 'Basisdaten' and the next heading.

PS: I should also mention the reason for `if not current.name`. I noticed some lines consisting of just new lines which BeautifulSoup treats as strings. These don't have names, hence the need to treat them specially in code.

```
import requests
import bs4
page = requests.get('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg').text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
def getInfoBoxBasisDaten(s):
    return str(s) == 'Basisdaten' and s.parent.name == 'th'

basisdaten = soup.find_all(string=getInfoBoxBasisDaten)[0]

wanted = 'Postleitzahlen:'
current = basisdaten.parent.parent.nextSibling
while True:
    if not current.name: 
        current = current.nextSibling
        continue
    if wanted in current.text:
        items = current.findAll('td')
        print (items[0])
        print (items[1])
    if '<th ' in str(current): break
    current = current.nextSibling
```

Result like this: two separate `td` elements, as requested.

```
<td><a href="/wiki/Postleitzahl_(Deutschland)" title="Postleitzahl (Deutschland)">Postleitzahlen</a>:</td>
<td>20095–21149,<br/>
22041–22769,<br/>
<a href="/wiki/Neuwerk_(Insel)" title="Neuwerk (Insel)">27499</a></td>
```

Comment: This seems to work for me if I use `BeautifulSoup.get_text()` to remove the html script etc. But unfirtunately I get an error on this site: `https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremen`.  Do you know what it is?

Comment: I have just looked at the wiki codes for the two pages (in the *Bearbeiten* views). They take completely different approaches toward formatting the pages and thus, the HTML is different. I have no German beyond high school. I see now that there's an 'Infobox' in the Bremen page but not in Hamburg's. This is the same situation as in the English-language wikipedia. If you want to scrape it then you need to be able to recognise what type of formatting you're dealing with and process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This works most of the time:

```
def get_content_from_right_column_for_left_column_containing(text):
    """return the text contents of the cell adjoining a cell that contains `text`"""

    navigable_strings = soup.find_all(text=text)

    if len(navigable_strings) > 1:
        raise Exception('more than one element with that text!')

    if len(navigable_strings) == 0:

        # left-column contents that are links don't have a colon in their text content...
        if ":" in text:
            altered_text = text.replace(':', '')

        # but `td`s and `th`s do.
        else: 
            altered_text = text + ":"

        navigable_strings = soup.find_all(text=altered_text)

    try:
        return navigable_strings[0].find_parent('td').find_next('td').text
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError('there are no elements containing that text.')
```